# SQL Server 2005 Copy Database Wizard keeps failing

Tags: sql-server, database, wizard

I am just trying to copy a database from one server to another one... on the same domain. I use the Copy DB Wizard and set up everything correctly but it keeps failing.

Is something wrong with the Wizard or just me missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have such a problem it's a good idea to provide information about the settings you made for instance on the priviledges on the remote server.

I would check the following:

1. Do you have the right permissions to be able to create the database on the other server i.e. dbcreator.
2. If you're not a sysadmin try to specify a SQL AGent Proxy that has acces to the SSIS execution system.
3. Make sure no active sessions exist on the database because the wizard will nog execute.

Can you provide an error message?